# Right way to get user's IP

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ip

I have the following code which is supposed to get user's IP:

```
public String getUserIP()
{
   Object details = getDetails();
   if (details instanceof WebAuthenticationDetails)
   {
     return ((WebAuthenticationDetails)details).getRemoteAddress();
   }
   return "";
}

@Nullable
public Object getDetails()
{
   Authentication authentication = getCurrentUserAuth();
   return authentication != null ? authentication.getDetails() : null;
}
```

However, under some unknown circumstances it returns `127.0.0.1` instead of real IP.

I decided to re-write like that:

```
public String getUserIP() 
{
  ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
  HttpServletRequest request = attr.getRequest();

  String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For").split(',')[0]; 

  return ip;
}
```

But in some cases the header `X-Forwarded-For` is null. The exception only occurs where `getUserIP()` from the first snippet returns valid IP address. What's the problem? The web server is tomcat. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Figure out the circumstances. The ip-address returned is the ip-address used. So if it returns localhost, the last one touching it was localhost. You might want to check if those are for instance anonymous checks, or maybe some stay alive check from some monitoring component.

Comment: I think it has to do with proxying or something similar. I assume that where `X-Forwarded-For` is absent when there's no proxy. And when there's a proxy we get localhost address when calling `getUserIP()`

Answer (score 0):

**You can update like this.**

```
public String getUserIP() 
{
  ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) 
  RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
  HttpServletRequest request = attr.getRequest();
  return request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Comment: Still gives me `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Check this resource. it may help. https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this

```
public static String getUserIP(HttpServletRequest request) {
String xForwardedForHeader = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
if (xForwardedForHeader == null) {
    return request.getRemoteAddr();
} else {
    // As of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
    // The general format of the field is: X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2 ...
    // we only want the client
    return new StringTokenizer(xForwardedForHeader, ",").nextToken().trim();
}
```

}

Comment: That's exactly what I did, however, I wonder what's wrong with tomcat configuration that it returns some mess. These two servers are different